# Teamcity Agent cannot Run the Build

Tags: git, teamcity

I am a Teamcity Developer. We Recently Moved out Teamcity Builds from local server to Public cloud instance.

Everything went well but couldn't able to run the build.

ERROR :

> Failed to perform checkout on agent: '/usr/bin/git init' command failed.
>   stderr: /usr/local/sg/chaldron/repo/chaldron-pngdev/.git: Permission denied

[image: error]

I am using Git latest and Java latest version.

Can anyone suggest how to solve the error?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which version of TC? I have no experience with using cloud-based TC but I've seen many improvements/fixes related to the cloud in the TC10 release notes.

Answer (score 5):

For whatever reason, the build agent does not have permission to access the git repo.

A few things to try:

1. Confirm that the git repo is in the location specified.
2. Confirm that there are no permissions configurations on the git repo (IP whitelists/blacklists etc) that might prevent access from this cloud agent
3. Check whether checking out on the teamcity server would work instead. In the version control settings for your build you can specify to checkout on the agent or checkout on the server (see below)

Hopefully one of these will point to your issue and let you resolve it

[image: version control settings of build configuration - dropdown to change checkout process]

Comment: Good advice! In my case setting as true the 'Clean all files in the checkout directory before the build' fixed my problem.